# Spark SQL: How to apply specific functions to all specified columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I there an easy way to call sql on multiple column on spark sql.

For example, Let's say I have a query that should be applied to most columns

```
select
min(c1) as min,
max(c1) as max,
max(c1) - min(c1) range
from table tb1
```

If there are multiple columns, is there a way to execute the query for all the columns, and get result one time.

Similar to how **df.describe** does.

Answer (score 1):

Use the meta data (columns in this case) included in your dataframe (which you can get via `spark.table("<table_name>")` if you don't have it in scope already to get the column names, then apply the functions you want and pass to `df.select` (or `df.selectExpr`).

Build some test data:

```
scala> var seq = Seq[(Int, Int, Float)]()
seq: Seq[(Int, Int, Float)] = List()

scala> (1 to 1000).foreach(n => { seq = seq :+ (n,r.nextInt,r.nextFloat) })

scala> val df = seq.toDF("id", "some_int", "some_float")
```

Denote some functions we want to run on all the columns:

```
scala> val functions_to_apply = Seq("min", "max")
functions_to_apply: Seq[String] = List(min, max)
```

Setup the final Seq of SQL Columns:

```
scala> var select_columns = Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]()
select_columns: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = List()
```

Iterate over the columns and functions to apply to populate the select_columns Seq:

```
scala> val cols = df.columns

scala> cols.foreach(col => { functions_to_apply.foreach(f => {select_columns = select_columns :+ expr(s"$f($col)")})})
```

Run the actual query:

```
scala> df.select(select_columns:_*).show

+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|min(id)|max(id)|min(some_int)|max(some_int)|min(some_float)|max(some_float)|
+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|      1|   1000|  -2143898568|   2147289642|   1.8781424E-4|     0.99964607|
+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```